# Copy/Move file program - Method is scanning the destination directory instead of source directory

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Javaapplication59 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//Create a new instance of scanner to get user input
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

//Ask user to input the directory to be copied
System.out.print("Input directory to be copied.");

//Save input as String
String dirName = scanner.nextLine();

//Ask user to input destination where direction will be copied
System.out.print("Input destination directory will be moved to.");

//Save input as String
String destName = scanner.nextLine();

//Run method to determine if it is a directory or file
isDirFile(dirName, destName);


}//end main

public static void isDirFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception{
//Create a File object for new directory in new location with same name
//as source directory
File dirFile = new File (dest, new File(source).getName());

//Make the new directory
dirFile.mkdirs();

//Create an array of File class objects for each item in the source
//directory
File[] entries; 

//If source directory exists
if (dirFile.exists()){
    //If the source directory is a directory
    if (dirFile.isDirectory()){

        //Get the data and load the array
        entries = new File(source).listFiles();

        //Iterate the array using alternate for statement
        for (File entry : entries){
            if (entry.isFile()){
                copyFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
            } //end if
            else {
                isDirFile (entry.getAbsolutePath(), dest);
            }  //end else if
        }//end for
    }//end if
}//end if
else {
    System.out.println("File does not exist.");
} //end else
}

public static void copyFile (String source, String dest) throws Exception {

//declare Files
File sourceFile = null;
File destFile = null;

//declare stream variables
FileInputStream sourceStream = null;
FileOutputStream destStream = null;

//declare buffering variables
BufferedInputStream bufferedSource = null;
BufferedOutputStream bufferedDest = null;

try {
    //Create File objects for source and destination files
    sourceFile = new File (source);
    destFile = new File (dest);

    //Create file streams for the source and destination
    sourceStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    destStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

    //Buffer the file streams with a buffer size of 8k
    bufferedSource = new BufferedInputStream(sourceStream,8182);
    bufferedDest = new BufferedOutputStream(destStream,8182);

    //Use an integer to transfer data between files
    int transfer;

    //Alert user as to what is happening
    System.out.println("Beginning file copy:");
    System.out.println("\tCopying " + source);
    System.out.println("\tTo      " + dest);

    //Read a byte while checking for End of File (EOF)
    while ((transfer = bufferedSource.read()) !=-1){

    //Write a byte
    bufferedDest.write(transfer);
}//end while

}//end try

catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("An unexpected I/O error occurred.");
}//end catch

finally {
    //close file streams
    if (bufferedSource !=null)
        bufferedSource.close();

    if (bufferedDest !=null)
        bufferedDest.close();

    System.out.println("Your files have been copied correctly and "
            + "closed.");
}//end finally
}//end copyDir

}//end class
```

So like the title says. This program copies from the source directory and moves it to the destination directory however I am getting a null exception error in the isDirFile method which I assume means the array which has all the data comes back as null which leads me to believe that the destination directory is being scanned and not the source directory and so far I cannot figure out why that is happening

edit: The output

`Input directory to be copied. C:/Users/jim/Desktop/pff.txt
Input destination directory will be moved to. C:/Users/jim/Desktop/bob
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javaapplication59.Javaapplication59.main(Javaapplication59.java:31)
at javaapplication59.Javaapplication59.main(Javaapplication59.java54)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)`

Which are the `isDirFile(dirName, destName);` and `for (File entry : entries){` lines

Comment: Where is the stacktrace showing where the NPE occurs?

Comment: Usually you'll get a `null` result from `listFiles` if the abstract path does not exist, is not a directory or can not be read by Java (like `My Music` directory on Windows)

Comment: So, running your code on my system seems to work fine (I listed the directory contents rather than copying them). I would verify the `source` and make sure it's a directory and not a "special link", which `java.io.File` can't process

Comment: @MadProgrammer I edited my output error into the original question. I'm just testing it with a simple text file

Comment: None of the output statements appear in your code snippet. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I apologize. I have added the full program